# How to get value by key from System.Collections.SortedList

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, sortedlist

I'm working with a C++/CLI program. And need to know how to retrieve a value from a SortedList using key. Here is what I tried. Anyone there to help?

```
gcroot <SortedList^> openConnections = foo1();
String^ dbGuid = gcnew String(foo2());
openConnections[dbGuid]; // It doesn't work this way
```

Answer (score 0):

With a sorted list, the value *is* the key. There is no separate thing to retrieve, you already have it.

From your example code, it looks like you want to look up a connection using a Guid. In that case, perhaps you want to use a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) instead.